# VB.Net data source connection error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqldatasource, sqlconnection

i am using VS2008 VB.net and sql 2008.

- I tried to connect a new datasource using Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient) it gives an error;
  [image: Microsoft SQL Server Database File]
- I tried to connect a new datasource using  Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient) it gives an error;
  [image: Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)]

Comment: Have you applied all the updates to VS, including SP1? I just tried Data->Add New Data Source and chose Database in the Choose a Data Source Type in the dialog, continued with the wizard, and it worked with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Comment: @RGI Nope. only SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, it appears you're attempting to attach to an active SQL Server database file that is actually being used by SQL Server and/or the permissions to the file don't grant you access to it. Either stop the local SQL Server to access the file, or find out how you would go about getting the file's permissions modified such that you can access it.

In the second instance, it sounds like an older version of the SqlClient simply doesn't support connection to database servers later than SQL Server 2005, as the error message implies. That would suggest the possibility of installing later patches/updates to get your configuration up to date.